# Difference between Array.method and [].method

Tags: javascript

```
Array.from([1,3,10,5], x => x + x); // [2,6,20,10]
[1,2,10,5].from( x => x + x); // TypeError
[1,3,10,5].pop(); // 5
```

Why different methods of Array are called in different way?

Comment: Array.method are methods of Array ... [].method are methods on the Array.prototype

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given an instance `arr` of `Array`, `arr.method` is equivalent to `Array.prototype.method`.

Notice the `.prototype` in there!

So `arr.pop()` will be the same as `Array.prototype.pop.call(arr)`. But, `Array.from` has no `prototype` in there, it's a method directly on the Array constructor itself, and can't (easily) be accessed using an array instance.

If you're familiar with other object-oriented languages (Java, C#, etc.), `Array.from` is essentially a static method, whereas `Array.prototype.pop` is essentially an instance method.

Answer (score 2):

`from` function exists in the `Array` object itself. So you need to call it via `Array` instance. You can also create an array with `new Array` or `[]` which differs from `Array`. When you create an array, it has nothing related to the functions of the `Array` instance. It only has a reference to the `Array.prototype` in it's prototype chain from which it gets functions and properties such as `length` or `pop`. Generally said what is in `Array.prototype` - are accessible from the array (`[]`), what is in the `Array` instance itself - are not and you need to call them via `Array` instance.

Answer (score 1):

In the second case, you want `map` to return a modified array using a function to apply on each element.

```
 [1,2,10,5].map(x => x + x); // [2,6,20,10]
```

*And that's actually what you want*, in my opinion.

---

More explanations on `Array.from`.

This is a function which is 'static', meaning that it cannot be applied on an actual array instance like you tried in the second line, it can be used only on the *class* `Array`. Put otherwise in Javascript terms, it's not part of `Array.prototype`.

Description from the docs to explain the purpose of the function :

From : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from

> Array.from() lets you create Arrays from:
>
> array-like objects (objects with a length property and indexed
>   elements) or iterable objects (objects where you can get its elements,
>   such as Map and Set).
>
> Array.from() has an optional parameter mapFn,
>   which allows you to execute a map function on each element of the
>   array (or subclass object) that is being created.
>
> More clearly,
>   Array.from(obj, mapFn, thisArg) has the same result as
>   Array.from(obj).map(mapFn, thisArg), except that it does not create an
>   intermediate array.

So, in your case, the use of `Array.from(yourArray, mapFunc)` seems a bit less clear than simply use `youArray.map(mapFunc)`, because the real interest of using Array.from is when you *don't* have an array, but something that *can be turned into* an array.

In this case, it's also convenient to give the mapFunction as second argument to avoid first creating a temporary array, then map the elements to a new final array.