# TypeError: Array.concat is not a function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

"I'm trying to use the `concat()` method in JavaScript to merge an object and several numbers into a new array. Here's the code I'm using:

```js
console.log(Array.concat({}, 1, 2, 3));
```

When I run this code, I get the following error message:

```js
TypeError: Array.concat is not a function
```

However, when I use `Array.prototype.concat.call()`, it works as expected:

```js
console.log(Array.prototype.concat({}, 1, 2, 3));
```

Why does `Array.concat()` cause an error, but `Array.prototype.concat.call()` works?"

Comment: That's because the [static method `Array.concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#static_methods) doesn't exist; the method `concat` only exists on the `prototype`…

Comment: What makes you think that `Array.concat` exists? It [used to exist](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#array) in some browsers as a non-standard feature years ago; have you encountered a tutorial that mentioned these static methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not a huge expert, but you might want to review:

[Array.prototype.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

In your terminal, web console, if you type Array.prototype, it will basically create an empty array with all of the methods for an array for you, so 'Array.prototype' is an array.

So,

```
Array.prototype.concat({}, 1, 2, 3)
```

and

```
[].concat({}, 1, 2, 3)
```

give the same result.

Given an instance arr of Array, arr.method is equivalent to Array.prototype.method.

You might read this as well:  [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49920564/difference-between-array-method-and-method)

Answer (score 1):

`concat()` method actually ....concats TWO(or more) arrays, it merges them. The way you are calling it, through `Array.prototype` is equivalent to doing `[].concat({}, 1, 2, 3)`
which means merge an empty array with the values `{},1,2,3`.

The proper way to use it is like

```
const num1 = [1, 2, 3];
const num2 = [4, 5, 6];
num1.concat(num2)
```

`Array.concat` doesn't exist as `concat` is a method of `Array.prototype`. The reason
`num1.concat(num2)` works is because `num1` is an `Array` with `prototype` object as property that contains all these array functions you can use